# Get real admob unit id for testing

Tags: android, admob

Now, I am testing my app with test id (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111). It is working properly. I want to test my app with real adUnitId. Is it possible? I read some articles on web how to get admob unit id before publishing the app on play store. But I don't understand how to do it. I don't see any option that I can get adUnitId before publishing my app. Following is the screenshot that appear when I click "Get started" on admob home page,
[image]

Comment: What type of ad you are using ? Banner, native or interstitial ?

Comment: @AkhileshAwasthi Do you mean ad format?

Comment: use `addTestDevice` with your real ad unit id

Comment: @ChetanShankar Please check my question again. I want to know how to get real ad unit id, not how to use inside app. I edited my question.

Comment: @NyeinChan you just need to click the **No** if you haven't publish your app and then after they will allow you to create new ad unit

Comment: yes the ad format. and have you created any ad unit on admob yet ?? You will get ad unit id of your ad when you create one an ad unit on admob.

Comment: you need to pass through some steps like selecting which type of ad unit you want to create.and after creating ad unit  you will find an ad unit id